# Running app puts up: "The application has failed to start because XYZ.DLL was not found." BUT it actually runs fine?

Tags: winapi, dll

I have a question, I came across running an x86 app on XP x64 that throws up a couple (2) of the "*The application has failed to start because XYZ.DLL was not found*".  My question is, it still runs fine!  So how does that work?  I know if some function is missing you get that and the app doesn't actually run.  What causes this message yet it runs fine?  I don't think `LoadLibrary()` would put up a message?  Is it from some `#pragma comment( lib, "XYZ.lib" )` in a library even if that module not used?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, it still runs fine! So how does that work?

If a DLL function is statically linked and can't be found at runtime, the OS will fail to create and run the process at all.  So, the obvious answer is that the DLL function is linked dynamically instead via calls to `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` at runtime.

> I know if some function is missing you get that and the app doesn't actually run.

If the missing DLL function is linked *statically*, yes.

> What causes this message yet it runs fine? I don't think LoadLibrary() would put up a message?

Actually, it can. Use [`SetErrorMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode) to avoid that. This is stated as much in the [`LoadLibrary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) documentation:

> To enable or disable error messages displayed by the loader during DLL loads, use the SetErrorMode function.

See [Silently catch windows error popups when calling LoadLibrary()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058303/).

> Is it from some #pragma comment( lib, "XYZ.lib" ) in a library even if that module not used?

Linking to a DLL's `.lib` creates static linkage to the DLL.  Unless the linker has a [delay-load feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2019) available AND the project is making use of that feature, in which case any *static* calls to the lib's referenced DLL functions are converted into runtime calls to `LoadLibrary()`/`GetProcAddress()` by the compiler+linker for you.